# How to use the Yoast SEO wpseo_canonical filter to set a canonical URL for /, /au/ & /uk/ sites in a MU environment

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rel-canonical

Our company has markets in USA, UK & Australia.

We've just started using WP MU on our development server where the USA/global version is @ `www.example.com`, and then there are `www.example.com/uk/` & `www.example.com/au/`.

We're probably going to create an AJAX function to redirect the visitor based on their geographical location to the appropriate website, with `www.example.com` being the catch-all.

I've come across the [Yoast SEO `wpseo_canonical filter`](https://developer.yoast.com/features/seo-tags/canonical-urls/api/) which might help us set a canonical URL for all of our posts and custom post types.

How would I use `wpseo_canonical filter` to set a canonical URL for the posts in `www.example.com/uk/`?

E.g. the blog post `www.example.com/uk/blog/post-1/` should have a canonical URL of `www.example.com/blog/post-1/` I believe.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I use `wpseo_canonical filter` to set a canonical URL for
> the posts in `www.example.com/uk/`?
>
> E.g. the blog post `www.example.com/uk/blog/post-1/` should have a
> canonical URL of `www.example.com/blog/post-1/` I believe.

I don't know if that *should* be the canonical URL, but if you are asking how can that be done, then this would do it, for the core `post` post type:

```php
function prefix_filter_canonical_example( $canonical ) {
    if ( ! is_main_site() && is_single() ) {
        // Get the ID of the main blog/site.
        $main_site_id = get_main_site_id();

        // Get the slug of the current post.
        $post_slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;

        // Switch to the main site and find a post with the same slug.
        switch_to_blog( $main_site_id );
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'name'      => $post_slug,
        ) );
        // If found, then use its permalink as the canonical URL.
        $permalink = empty( $posts ) ? '' : get_permalink( $posts[0] );
        restore_current_blog();

        return $permalink ? $permalink : $canonical;
    }

    return $canonical;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'prefix_filter_canonical_example' );
```

Or if all the sites use the same **permalink structure**, e.g. `%postname%`, *and that the same post also exists in the main site* (i.e. same slug and post type), then you could simply use the current post's permalink and just replace the WordPress "home" URL in that permalink.. E.g.

```php
function prefix_filter_canonical_example( $canonical ) {
    if ( ! is_main_site() && is_single() ) {
        // Get the ID of the main blog/site.
        $main_site_id = get_main_site_id();

        // Get the data of the main and current sites.
        $main_blog    = get_blog_details( $main_site_id );
        $current_blog = get_blog_details();

        // Replace the home URL in the current post's permalink.
        return str_replace( "$current_blog->home/", "$main_blog->home/", get_permalink() );
    }

    return $canonical;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'prefix_filter_canonical_example' );
```

So I hope that helps, but remember that [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) does not switch *plugins*, and thus `get_permalink()` might not return the "correct" permalink that would otherwise be returned if plugins were also switched.

Also, a hook can run in various places on the same page, so you might want to cache the result of the `$permalink` value in the 1st snippet above..